# Is it possible to increase amperage and voltage?

Tags: voltage, current, lithium-ion, amperage, laptop

I have an input of 5V and 2 amps from a USB battery pack. Using this voltage and amperage, could it be possible to increase both values?

Here is an extremely simple representation of my idea.
[image: 3.7V > 5V 2A > 12V 3.25A]

Comment: No. [conservation of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy)

Comment: to answer your informal question, you can boost the 5v to 12v and your laptop should be able to charge from that, though not as quickly as from the OEM transformer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking no... due to conservation of energy you can't sustainably put out more power than the plug will give you...

However, if you have enough charge storage, you can deliver that amount periodically.

**EDIT BASED ON MORE INFO IN COMMENTS**

If all you are trying to do is boost it to charge your laptop, then yes you could do this. The current would be lower and it will take longer to charge. It would be horrendously inefficient though... Assuming the initial convert to 5V is at 75%..another boost would bring you down to about 56%...

Comment: So, I couldn't use my battery pack to charge my laptop's battery? Its capacity is only 4400mAh. Surely using a 22400 mAh battery 
 to charge a 4400 mAh battery would work?

Comment: @DavidWheatley Can you fill a 1 liter bottle with a 340ml cup? Yes. If you use it three times.

Comment: In my case it's the other way: Can you fill a 340ml cup with a 1 litre bottle - yes with a lot to spare.

Comment: You did not ask whether you can charge your laptop with a battery. You asked the wrong question for that. You only need to step up the voltage you don't actually have to supply 3.25 A

Comment: @Mike I just based it on 3.25 A because that is what my charger supplies.

Comment: @DavidWheatley the battery is meaningless in your question. You are saying you are feeding through 5V @ 2A..which is a tad high for USB but anyway.. that's 10W.. you need 39W. Don't confuse mAh with amps either..

Comment: If just double checked: it's actually 5V @ 2.1A. I'm guessing that I need to generate 28.5W out of think air?

Comment: @DavidWheatley as mike mentioned if all you are trying to do is use it to charge your laptop then yes, though at a lower current and longer time. It would be horrendously inefficient though...  Assuming the initial convert to 5V is at 75%..another boost would bring you down to about 56%...

Comment: Comparing Amps and Ah does NOT work... Only use Wh and efficiency loss

Answer (score 1):

You want 12VDC to charge your laptop from a USB connection rated for 5V 2A being sourced from a 3.7VDC battery. So in the first place if you must have 12V feed to your laptop, you would need a "boost converter" power supply that can take your 3.7VDC up to 12VDC. Otherwise, the best your source battery can do is charge your laptop battery to 3.7VDC, which most likely is what your laptop will interpret as "low power" and either shut down or at best, give you limited functionality.

So then let's say you do get (or make) a switch mode boost converter to get your battery source up to 11-13VDC for the laptop, then you have another problem, the limit of your USB connection and source battery. 5V 2A is 10VA (10W), the charger for your laptop is supplying 12V 3.25A max, which is 39W and means (ostensibly) that your laptop battery is going to try to draw that much when discharged. That is almost 4x what the USB cord and plug is rated. It likely is not capable of that amount of power and will over heat. Likewise your 3.7V battery will have to put out roughly 10A of current, also likely more than its internal circuits are capable of. Bottom line, something isn't going to like it. So your boost converter will then need to also be capable of limiting the current draw from the source, which will limit the current available to the laptop. Will it work? Possibly, but you may not like how long it takes to charge your laptop battery, in fact if the PC is running, it may still demand more than this source can deliver safely.